# Python Parse Structered Datafile to CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have a big (75MB) datafile (EMP.txt) which looks like

```
01ABCD      FIT        PROGRAMMER30000EFGH            
02IJK     LMMACCOUNTS  MANAGER   50000OPQRST   UV
```

and so on.
I have a structure file (EMPSTRU.txt) of the datafile which looks like

```
001 EMPID LENGTH 2
002 EMPNAME LENGTH 10
003 SEX LENGTH 1
004 DEPARTMENT LENGTH 10
005 DESIGNATION LENGTH 10
006 SALARY LENGTH 5
007 SUPERNAME LENGTH 10
```

Now how do I parse the datafile to csv format? I am using slice method to extract from the datafile. Also there are at least 150 field names. Is there a better way in python to get the column names? Currently I am manually typing them like

```
EMPID = Dataline(0:2)
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the `EMPSTRU.txt` file directly to a description usable by `struct.unpack`, for example

```
import struct
print(struct.unpack("2s3s2s", "abcdefg"))
```

outputs

```
["ab", "cde", "fg"]
```

In your case it should requires something like... (untested)

```
import struct

rdef = ""
colnames = []
for L in open("EMPSTRU.txt"):
    L = L.strip()
    lpos = L.rindex(" LENGTH ")
    rdef += L[lpos+8:] + "s"
    colnames.append(L[4:lpos]) # skip field number
```

then you can extract a data record with:

```
content = struct.unpack(rdef, record)
```

and rewrite it to destination file with

```
out.write("\t".join(content) + "\n")
```